# How to get query execution time in sqlite.swift?

Tags: query-performance, sqlite.swift

So SQLite.swift is quite awesome. I have it tracing my SQL queries using:

```
db.trace { SQL in
    print(SQL)
}
```

It works fine. However, I'd like to add SQL execution time as well on the output.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: great question ....